# Why getDerivedStateFromProps is called again even though Parent Props aren't updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following [this guide](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-16-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-f4ad31fb2282) on LifeCycle Methods in React & I tweaked a demo in that guide a little bit like https://codesandbox.io/s/m7m4qz6pqp

It is a simple app which uses all React's new lifecycle methods & adds Grids to the bottom every 10 seconds (so wait for 10 seconds & then see the **console**).

The way I understand **getDerivedStateFromProps** is they get called when the parent props change but in this sandbox if you check the console, it gets called even when the props aren't changed.

I've added some helpful `console.log`'s tracing the order.

Right now, it shows this in the **Console**

```
getDerivedStateFromProps - 1, 4 
render - 2, 6 
render - 2
componentDidMount - 3 
getDerivedStateFromProps - 1, 4
```

This means

`getDerivedStateFromProps` gets called 1st due to `1, 4`
`render` gets called 2nd due to `2, 6`
`render` of Error component gets called after that which we can ignore
`componentDidMount` gets called 3rd due to `3`
`getDerivedStateFromProps` gets called 4th due to `1, 4`

Now I understand every other order. I just didn't understand why `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called the 4th time `1, 4`.

Can anyone explain why this happens as I am not seeing any props change after 1st time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly in version of React 16.3, getDerivedStateFromProps() just was invoked when updating props(http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/). But now in version of React 16.4, `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is invoked when updating props and updating state (regardless of the reason for re-rendering). So in your condition,

`getDerivedStateFromProps()` is invoked before render() method under that conditions;

1. Initial mount
2. Every state and prop updating

Your component will be rendered every blocks update in per 10 sec and `getDerivedStateFromProps()` will invoked in every 10 sec consequently.

Comment: Thanks, @sdkcy that was easy in the way you explained it :)